# word for "obedient to a fault"?

Tags: meaning

What's a word meaning "obedient to a fault"? I heard it recently but don't recall the word.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @J.Taylor I Googled "obedient to a fault". I came here and searched "obedient to a fault". Curious as to why people are marking this as off-topic, I've seen many highly voted questions just like this on this site. Seems to be one of the more popular question types here.

Comment: There might have been the thought that one could have easily explored synonyms of "obedient"  and found the desired word fairly quickly.

Comment: @J.Taylor I mean, it's not listed as a synonym on [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obedient) or [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obedient?s=t), and even on [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obedient) it's not listed as a synonym, but it listed as a related word. So like any question asked here, you could argue that the answer could be found elsewhere, and the question of how easy it is to find seems entirely subjective. How does one define how far someone must look first before asking here? 3 Google results? 4? 5? 10?

Comment: I had not been one to claim you were off topic. I thought, though, that evidence of research was appropriate.  Combine your cites and question next time, and I do not think there could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Obsequious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsequious), perhaps?

> marked by or exhibiting a fawning attentiveness

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest '**subservient**'.

> 3. Of a person, action, etc.: characterized by or displaying an attitude of slavish submission;

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/192987?redirectedFrom=subservient#eid)

> Britain should threaten ‘weak’ and ‘**subservient**’ Ireland to get its way on Brexit

[The Independent - 27th November 2017](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-ukip-ireland-weak-subservient-northern-ireland-border-gerard-batten-leo-varadkar-a8077676.html)

> 1966   L. Fermi Mussolini iv. xxiii. 437   Mussolini..had reverted to his humble origins and clumsily **bowed in subservient fashion** before the man he had once considered his pupil.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/192987?redirectedFrom=subservient#eid)

Answer (score 1):

***Servile***

> Servile:  [meanly or cravenly submissive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/servile)

There's also the clumsier-sounding, more exactly fitting answer, ***overobedient***

> Overobedient: [overly obedient](https://www.litscape.com/word_analysis/overobedient)